# Value Error: Too many values to unpack django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am creating a filterable search page in django that allows users to search the database based on people that match some or all of the requirements in the form. Because I don't know which attribute they will select

My views.py

```
class SearchFilter(View):
    form_class = SearchByFilter
    initial = {'tattoo': False, 'scar_marks': False, 'polydactyly': False}
    template_name = 'donors/donor_search_attr.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
    args = {'form': form}

    return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        ethnicity = form.cleaned_data['ethnicity']
        skintone = form.cleaned_data['skintone']
        eyecolor = form.cleaned_data['eyecolor']
        haircolor = form.cleaned_data['haircolor']
        body_build = form.cleaned_data['body_build']
        tattoo = form.cleaned_data['tattoo']
        scar_marks = form.cleaned_data['scar_marks']
        polydactyly = form.cleaned_data['polydactyly']
        nose = form.cleaned_data['nose']
        facial = form.cleaned_data['facial']
        race = form.cleaned_data['race']
        academic_info = form.cleaned_data['academic_info']
        blood_group = form.cleaned_data['blood_group']
        genotype = form.cleaned_data['genotype']

        filter_values = {'ethnicity': ethnicity, 'skintone': skintone, 'eyecolor': eyecolor, 'haircolor': haircolor,
                         'body_build': body_build, 'nose': nose, 'facial': facial, 'race': race, 'academic_info':
                             academic_info, 'blood_group': blood_group, 'genotype': genotype}

        d = ['donorprofile__tattoo__name={}'.format(tattoo), 'donorprofile__scar_marks__name={}'.format(scar_marks),
             'donorprofile__polydactyly__name={}'.format(polydactyly)]

        for table_name, values in filter_values.items():
            if values:
                data_format = 'donorprofile__{}__name={}'.format(table_name, values)
                d.append(data_format)

            # print(d)
        donors = donor.objects.filter(d)
        # donors = donor.objects.filter(Q(donorprofile__ethnicity__name=ethnicity) | Q(donorprofile__skintone__name=skintone) |
        #                               Q(donorprofile__eyecolor__name=eyecolor) | Q(donorprofile__haircolor__name=haircolor) |
        #                               Q(donorprofile__body_build__name=body_build))

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'donors': donors, 'filter_values': d})
```

Comment: Is there Something I am doing wrong that does not make it work

Comment: What is your problem? Is there an error? Does it not work? If it doesn't what does it do and what do you expect it to do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create list with kwargs. Use something like this:

```
values = [tattoo, scar_marks, polydactyly]
table_names = ['donorprofile__tattoo__name', 'donorprofile__scar_marks__name', 'donorprofile__polydactyly__name']
for table_name, value in filter_values.items():
    if value:
        data_format = 'donorprofile__{}__name'.format(table_name)
        table_names.append(data_format)
        values.append(value) 
kwargs = dict(zip(table_names, values))
donors = donor.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks...really helped...I had to learn the use of kwargs. I will post my final code soon. Thank you so much